# can anyone help i.d. this bike?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I can not find any numbers on frame, only the crown on tank.[image]

Comment: FYI that blue bike in the background has the front fork rotated 180 degrees.  Not safe to ride like that because it steers like a drunk rabbit.

Comment: Any text on the bike might help a lot.

Comment: Yeah I've spent time searching, and all I have is a generic schwinn style sting-ray bike that someone has added an aftermarket "fuel tank" style thing.  Is it a front light or is that all cosmetic ?

Comment: @Criggie -- Pretty sure the "tank" is original.

Answer (score 5):

After a time on bing it looks a lot like a Vintage Murray Sportcrest or Sears Murray Sportcrest.

There is a pic of one here: https://uk.pinterest.com/pin/54465476715653140/

And on ebay here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Murray-26-Boys-Bike-Good-condition-/201618469157?hash=item2ef165b125
[image]
[image]

When searching for Vintage Murray Bicycles there are others by the same manufacturer pictured with very similar frame shape, the extra top tube that curves down and joins the down tube.

km

Comment: Yeah, and the crown logo matches.

Comment: Brilliant work with the search results - I've taken the liberty of bringing two photos in-line so that when ebay deletes the listing, the photos will remain for future searchers.   Keep up the good work!