# What make and model is this bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image] can you tell me what make and model this bicycle is?  And maybe tell me what year and how much it may be worth?

Comment: Probably from the 50s or early 60s.  Looks like one of the brands sold by outfits such as Western Auto.

Comment: Does the fake gas tank have a light in the black bit at the front? Or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: As to how much it's worth, item valuations are "off topic" but the basic answer would be "not much", unless the bike is in excellent condition (which it isn't, as I can see a lot of rust).

Comment: You can check the rear hub for a date. Some old bikes used to engrave the dates on the hubs. Could you post pictures from other sides and angles?

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41622/can-anyone-help-i-d-this-bike/41625 - you appear to have the same bike.

Comment: I tried to share this on Reddit:  https://www.reddit.com/r/Vintage_bicycles  If my submission didn't go through, then feel free to do so yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I had one just like it many years ago. Not a good collectible, and not worth much. It's an old Murray.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! The expectation on this site is that you give a detailed explanation in your answer. In this case, and explanation of how you identify the bike as a Murray, and why it's not worth much would be appropriate. Short answers that don't include any details about why your answer or solution is correct will be down-voted and are likely to be deleted. Please [take the tour](//bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information about how this and other Stack Exchange sites work.

Comment: Murrays from google image search have distinctly different seatstay bridge design.